# failed to create json file in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to save scrapped data in json file. I have used scrapy to scrap the data from web.

here is my spider code.

```
import scrapy
import json

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1//']

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('quotes.json', 'a') as f:
            for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
                json.dump({
                     'text' : quote.css('span:text::text').extract_first(),
                     'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
                     'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
                     }, f)
```

When I execute this command `scrapy crawl quotes`, it finished successfully, but json file is not being created.

Please tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: `http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1//` doesn't work, try with `http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/`. Also, values in `allowed_domains` shouldn't contain url path: `['quotes.toscrape.com']`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional parameter to your crawl command like:

```
scrapy crawl quotes -o output.json
```

json will be saved in the current folder from where you will execute the above command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the json programmatically you should use [Item Pipelines](http://If%20you%20want%20to%20store%20the%20json%20programmatically%20you%20should%20use%20https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)